# TestNG file is not reading parameter value if add another script

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

i am trying to run multiple test in sequence in in one by one different browser , for that i am defining browser parameter in testNg.xml file .

```
   <test name="iexplore">
      <parameter name="browser" value="iexplore"/>
      <classes>
        <class name="com.slingmedia.safe.testscripts.BRO_139"/>
       <class name="com.slingmedia.safe.testscripts.BRO_140"/>
      </classes>
 </test>
```

its working fine and taking correct browser , but when i am defining all the test in other xml file and trying to run , browser value is not getting read.

```
   <test name="iexplore">
     <parameter name="browser" value="iexplore"/>
      <suites-file>
       <suite path="Sample3.xml" />
      </suites-files>
  </test>
```

Comment: Show us your Sample3.xml code. And which testng version are you using?

Comment: and how are your running this?

Comment: <suite name="Sample3" parallel="false">
    <test name="test1">
      <classes>
        <class name="com.testscripts.test_139"/>
      </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="test2">
      <classes>
        <class name="com.testscripts.test140"/>
      </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="test3">
      <classes>
        <class name="com.testscripts.test143"/>
      </classes>
    </test>
   
  </suite>

Comment: i cant provide browser name in sample3.xml file , using latest version of testNG

Comment: this file is part of framework , which is reading value and executing

Comment: `suites-file` is not at the good place and it is not supposed to work at all. Check the DTD on TestNG.org and fix your suite file.